# Download installer from the webpage using php

Tags: php, web-scraping

I tried to download the docker for desktop from the webpage 
 the link as follows . 
https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker for Windows Installer.exe

when i try the same link in the browser it is downloading the exe file but from the php code when i try like

`fopen('https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker for Windows Installer.exe','wb');`

it says "PHP Warning:  fopen(https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker for Windows Installer.exe): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /workspace/Main.php on line 3"

Any help in how to download th exe file.

Comment: (If you don’t need too much error handling and sophistication with this, then a combination of file_get_contents and file_put_contents is probably the “quickest” way to achieve this. Requires config option allow_url_fopen to be activated.)

Answer (score 1):

The flag needs to be 'rb' (read binary) instead of 'wb' (write binary), because you can only read the file, not put it on the dockers server.

So change the line to

```
fopen('https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker for Windows Installer.exe','rb');
```